# How to resolve java.sql.SQLException: in integration of database with JDBC API?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Code snippet:

```
package dbIntegrationwithJDBC;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        String host = "localhost";
        String port = "3306";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/mastro1729", "root",
                "mysql123");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select*from credentials where Scenario='mastro1729'");
        System.out.println(rs.getString("Username"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("Password"));

        while (rs.next()) {

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com");

            driver.findElement(By.name("usernameOrEmail")).sendKeys(rs.getString("Username"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Continue']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(rs.getString("Password"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Log In']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mastro1729
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dbIntegrationwithJDBC.Example1.main(Example1.java:23)
```

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database with JDBC API. I created the MySQL database with mastro1729 on localhost. My code seems correct and I have added mysql-connector-java.jar file to eclipse. While I am trying to integrate my database with JDBC API I am getting `java.sql.SQLException at  DriverManager.getConnection();` statement. I have tried my best and but I could not be able to resolve the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you look at the project in Eclipse's "Package Explorer" do you see the jar file listed under "Referenced Libraries"?

Comment: Either you don't have the driver on the runtime classpath, or you are using an extremely old version that doesn't support automatic driver loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no suitable JDBC driver found in project classpath...

- Download platform independent [MySQL JDBC Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) from here.
- Extract downloaded `.zip`
- Add executable `.jar` to your project's classpath.

Comment: I am afraid, Could you please provide me the navigation to download MySQL JDBC Driver?

Comment: Open `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=479586`, scroll down to bottom to this page, click `No thanks, just start my download.` This will start downloading .zip

Comment: I have already downloaded and added the MySQL JDBC Connector in Eclipse.

Comment: Did you see, .jar file in project explorer?

Comment: Gaurav Could you please let me know step by step Navigation of the MySQL Connector Jave.jar file.

Comment: @ManideepLatchupatula, I don't understand what do you mean by step by step navigation? Did your error resolve?

Comment: Gaurav I mean I am asking you to provide me the step by step navigation for https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=479586.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179437/discussion-between-gaurav-genius-and-manideep-latchupatula).

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the mysql connector jar file in the classpath. 
If you are using maven, import mysql-connector-java dependency.

If not, you can download the binary and provide it in classpath (either via shell or using IDE)
See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html